# How to create a custom outbound IDoc and send data to the same sever and to different clients

Tags: sap-erp, idoc

The requirement to create custom Outbound IDoc:

Sales Order Data: VBAK - Header Table and VBAP - Item Table - 5 fields from each table and create the segment as Header and Item.

So whenever I hit run to the program, IDoc should trigger and be sent to the client.
How should I approach this problem?

I have created the segments correctly; also, I have created the program, but whenever I hit the program, it shows the current status 29.

Can you guys provide me step-by-step guidance so that I can rectify my errors and if there are any missing steps in the process, then I go futher with that.

Comment: I'm going to assume you've created a custom IDoc type and are now trying to send it somewhere. Have you set up a receiving partner profile (transaction WE20 / SALE, depending on your setup)? Error 29 usually means the system doesn't have the partner profile to send the idoc.

Comment: Yes, I have set up the partner's profile. but still there it is showing the error.
One small doubt is do I need to assign the same name to RFC and partner profile.